# The clock isn’t working or has stopped

Tags: grammar

When the clock hands don’t move because its battery is dead.

Is it possible to say like these?

The clock isn’t working.

The clock has stopped.

The clock stops.

The clock stops moving.

The clock is dead.

Can you tell me how you call it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your third choice is correct: *The clock has stopped*

Your choices cover varying levels of severity for these kinds of devices (e.g., mechanical, electrical) and in order from least severe to most severe they are:

> stopped << not working << dead.

Saying the clock is *dead* indicates that it can't be fixed in the same way that a dead person cannot be revived.

If it's just the battery that's *dead* you throw it out and get a new one. But the clock itself isn't dead; it just needs a new battery.

Often when you know the clock has stopped because the battery is dead (or it needs to be wound) you say so by following up with the reason:

> The clock has stopped [again]. I think it needs a new battery.

Saying the clock isn't working usually means that the clock needs to be fixed before it will function properly.

Sometimes people might attribute a more severe state to the clock because they don't know the actual state.  They might say the clock is dead or isn't working when they don't know why and it might just be that it needs a new battery.  In that case it isn't really dead and a conversation about it might go something like:

> The clock's dead/not working.
>   No, it just needs a new battery.